# Political Analysis - Chance that similar event happens in future

Tags: politics

Part 1

Say there is a county (or state) that in each of the past 20 elections was 5% more (Blue, or Red) than another county or state.

What is the probability that it would have the same 5% variant in the next election?

Part 2

Say there are multiple such scenarios (say 10). What is the possibility of all occurring? Or, conversely none of them occurring.

Sample data.

- County A has voted 5% more blue than County B for 10 straight elections.
- County X has voted 5% more red than County Y for 10 straight elections.
- All candidates that had more "x" than "y" have won in the last 10 elections.

I'm comfortable with basic probability but don't know how to start approaching something like this. This is not a pure chance analysis such as a coin toss. Or is it as voters come of age, die out, and move. But it cannot be pure chance because voting habits are fixed (as opposed to a coin toss.)

I'm running around in circles here, which is why I'm posting this question. :)

EDIT:

The underlying question comes from people saying things such as

County X or State X has voted for the winner of the Presidential election for each of the last 10 elections, therefore (something not relevant to this discussion).

My question, in a nutshell is if:

- State X has voted for the winner the last 10 times AND
- State Y has voted for the winner the last 10 times what is the probability that neither state would vote for the winner this time?

Edit 2
Here's another one I've heard. No Incumbent President, who received more votes the second time running has lost. (Until 2020) Statistically does it mean anything? And if not, why not? I'm at a lost at dealing with these claims.

Answer (score 1):

Probabilities are mathematical constructs that can be determined within probability models. They don't exist in the real world outside such models. So the probabilities you are interested in could be determined if you had a detailed enough model for voting over time. Note that reality itself will not give you such a model, rather a model has to be set up and then data needs to be fed into it in order to estimate its parameters or (if you run a Bayesian analysis) update them taking into account the available information.

Even if you have such a model and run the calculations, the model may be criticised for observed discrepancies compared to reality, or for implausible implicit assumptions. If you want to make the model even remotely realistic, you need to put in a lot of effort. If you can do it, what Peter Flom writes still holds, namely that you need to specify an event that allows for some random variation; normally the event that a result *exactly* repeats itself will have probability zero or extremely low.

You may want to read [M. Heidemanns, A. Gelman, G. E. Morris (2020) An Updated Dynamic Bayesian Forecasting Model for the US Presidential Election](https://hdsr.mitpress.mit.edu/pub/nw1dzd02/release/2) to get an idea of what it takes.

Answer (score 0):

First, this hasn't occurred. That is, you don't get 20 repetitions where two counties are different by exactly 5%, there is always variation.  I'd be surprised if there were any two counties where this was true, even approximately (say 4 to 6%) and, if there were, it would be hard to say why. There are 3143 counties in the US, so that's almost 10 million pairs.

For state level data in POTUS elections, states switch party preference far more than people think. E.g. if we go back to 1988 (10 elections ago), we see that Iowa went Democratic, as did West Virginia, while Delaware went Republican.

Second, even if this did happen (or even if the question was modified to give the actual numbers) there would be no way to know. Politics doesn't work that way.

This reads like a really bad question, written to get at some point of probability and adding context, but the context makes the problem nonsensical. It's not even completely clear what underlying point the question is trying to get at.